# Microservice for running cron job in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, cron

Application design question here :
I have a spring boot application and I am tasked with designing a cron job that will run every 1 hour, collect some data from our RDS database and send it to a shared redshift instance. Redshift instance is used by the mode analytics tool to extract some data and run some reports for the concerned people.

Question is : should I be writing a new microservice just for this job ? We don't want this to be a part of our application anymore because this task is kind of heavy and irrelevant to the actual application. But if I write a service for this it will be sitting idle when cron job is not running and wasting resources. Is lambda better for this ?

Comment: Scheduler will be running in background, but it will not consume very less resources. Should be easily manageable. It should be the resources consumed by the actual job you should think about.

Comment: Correction: <but it will not consume very less resources> but it will consume very less resources.

Comment: But there's aws cost associated with continuous running scheduler

Comment: I mostly use GCP, but I'm sure AWS must have a managed service for running scheduled tasks with API to allocate resources for Jobs. But, you can spin up a cheapest VM and run scheduler on that.

Comment: If this task is not going to run frequently then why even write a new service (which runs 24x7)? Use a managed workflow orchestration service which run this Job based on a schedule (or a trigger).

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosted on **AWS**, it's definitely a better alternative to run it in the serverless environment with [scheduled] job. This will significantly reduce your AWS bill and save your company money. If you need to just dump those reports, use S3. In case you need intensive IOPS and/or availability among multiple availability zones then use EFS.  (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents-expressions.html).

Just create the lambda and schedule it with CloudWatch *every hour*.
[image: cloudwatch flow]

If you host **Kubernetes**, you can also create CronJob.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Source: [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/)

Comment: we are on aws, and host k8s as well. But the problem with k8s job is since it's not inside the application it won't be able to access rds to fetch data. I am not sure if this understanding is right or not.

Comment: It is better to place inside of the cluster and do it via the API layer if possible, so you can rely on the long-lasting endpoint. However, if integration through the database is your only choice, you can create a lambda and give it RDS read-only (and/or write) role as well.